# Bug in my Javascript Code: Scope Issue or Logic Issue?

Tags: javascript

My snake game is leaving a trail everywhere it goes, rather than moving properly: http://jaminweb.com/Snake.html
(Move it with the arrow keys)

I'm wondering whether this might be a problem of scope.

The relevant code is

```
var temp = this.body[0].clone();
// ....
this.body[0].translate(this.dx, this.dy);
for (var i = 1, j = this.body.length; i < j; ++i)
{
    var lastBB = temp.getBBox();
    var thisBB = this.body[i].getBBox();
    temp = this.body[i].clone();
    this.body[i].translate(lastBB.x-thisBB.x,lastBB.y-thisBB.y);
}
```

I'm wondering, dees

```
temp = this.body[i].clone();
```

inside the `for` loop create a new variable or does Javascript look outside to see if there's already one? I assumed the latter.

Comment: There's no block scope in Javascript. If both uses of `temp` fall within the same function then they're the same variable.

Comment: note that even if there were block scope, you'd need to say `var temp = ...` to get a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

`temp = this.body[i].clone();` creates a new object, thus you are creating new objects that don't get translated.

And as @MikeW pointed out in the comments, there is no `for` block scope in JavaScript; scoping is either global or limited to a function. So, `temp` in your code is the same variable both inside and outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score -2):

the this variable always points to the context that it is defined in.

```
function Constructor1
{
    this.x = 1;   // points to the objects instantiated by Constructor1
}

var a = new Constructor1;
a.x = 1;    // `this` points to a
var b = new Constructor1;
b.x = 1;    // `this` points to b

function func()
{
    return this;    // points to the calling function, returns itself
}

func() will return the function itself
```

Javascript uses functional scope as opposed to block scope.